# Rails - Update attributes with best in place gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, best-in-place

Using best in place  to update  a attribute in a Order form rails spit out `undefined method`update_attributes' for #`

the form is not on a update action but in a sold action, so the form must be inside of a update action?

```
          <%= best_in_place order, :track_number, :as => :input, :nil => "Track code", :url => sold_order_path(order)%> 



        Mark as:

            <%= link_to "Sent",  sent_order_path(order), :class => 'btn btn_small' %>






def sold
    @q = Order.where('seller_id = ? and status = ?', current_vitrine.id, params[:status] || Order.statuses[0]).ransack(params[:q])
    @orders = @q.result(distinct: true).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 22)

 @order = Order.find_by_id(params[:id]) 


     respond_to do |format|
      if Order.where('seller_id = ? and status = ?', current_vitrine.id, params[:status] || Order.statuses[0]).update_attributes(params[:order])
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@order) }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'sold' }
        format.json { respond_with_bip(@order) }
      end
    end

  end
```

Comment: what object do you call the update_attributes method on?

Comment: Hello @FabrizioBertoglio thanks, order!

Comment: i do not have any idea, sorry.  Did you try this query with the rails console `if Order.where('seller_id = ? and status = ?', current_vitrine.id, params[:status] || Order.statuses[0])`
did you try to debug this with `binding.pry`?
Would be good making sure the query is actually returning something

Comment: it is not saying that the object is `nil`, it is saying that the object is `#`. When does ruby it returns `#`?

Comment: no just return   Order Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE (seller_id = ? and status = ?)
=> []

Comment: So if an order is sold you update the attributes, else you redirect to the action. In this case no order is sold, because it return an empty array `[]`.
I am still wondering the meaning of `#`. He calls on that query the update attributes and then give you the error on `#`. So usually the error is undefined method for `#<Object:0x00000008759718>`